# Google map sdk for ios- how to find onmylocationchange in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, navigation

I am developing an app similar to google map navigation . i found google map sdk having a method for finding location changes in android (OnMyLocationChangeListener). but i didn't get a similar method for iOS . please advise me how to do that in ios. sample code is appreciated

Comment: You can use core location framework which will help you to determine user's location as well notify whenever user's location is changed.

Comment: Check the delegate methods